# Trouble with cumsum and decimal numbers

Tags: pandas, numpy, cumsum

Suppose the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
   
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)})
df['B'] = df['A'].diff()

x, x_diff = 1, df['B'].iloc[1:]
df['C'] = np.r_[x, x_diff].cumsum()

   A    B    C
# 0  6  NaN  1.0
# 1  6  0.0  1.0
# 2  0 -6.0 -5.0
# 3  7  7.0  2.0
# 4  5 -2.0  0.0
# 5  3 -2.0 -2.0
# 6  3  0.0 -2.0
# 7  8  5.0  3.0
# 8  8  0.0  3.0
# 9  8  0.0  3.0
```

Column C is beautifully changing as expected. This seems to work without trouble. However, when I use decimal numbers then they get rounded to 0 and I end up with the starting value not changing at all. Any ideas how to prevent this? Theoretically I could multiply the numbers again, but is there a better way to resolve this? The problem is demonstrated below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)})/100000000000000


df['B'] = df['A'].diff()

x, x_diff = 1, df['B'].iloc[1:]
df['C'] = np.r_[x, x_diff].cumsum()

#               A             B    C
# 0  9.000000e-14           NaN  1.0
# 1  7.000000e-14 -2.000000e-14  1.0
# 2  1.000000e-14 -6.000000e-14  1.0
# 3  9.000000e-14  8.000000e-14  1.0
# 4  9.000000e-14  0.000000e+00  1.0
# 5  4.000000e-14 -5.000000e-14  1.0
# 6  6.000000e-14  2.000000e-14  1.0
# 7  9.000000e-14  3.000000e-14  1.0
# 8  7.000000e-14 -2.000000e-14  1.0
# 9  0.000000e+00 -7.000000e-14  1.0
```

Comment: This is not an issue of decimal numbers, it's an issue of numbers being too small. The computer is effectively treating them as zeros, because there's a minimal difference of orders of magnitudes you can handle in a computer. All you can do about this is have C start at 0 isntead of 1, if that works for your usecase.

Comment: You can check if that's the case by querying your [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) like so: `eps = np.finfo(float).eps`. You should get `1+eps >1` but adding anything smaller than `eps` should be 1. You'll need to replace `float` with whatever data type you are actually using (for instance, `numpy.float32` has an eps of about 10^-7)

Comment: If I use your code on a 64bit implementation and set the precision to 16 `pd.set_option('precision', 16)` then column `B` can be seen to `cumsum` into column `C`.  Or as @Puff said start Column `C` from zero not one.  Another way to show it would be to add a `df['D'] = df['C'] - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the many suggestions. Using 0 as starting value as suggested by PUFF worked. Also the method with `pd.set_option('precision', 16)` as suggested by Chris worked.